# "One for," or "one to," or perhaps something else

Tags: idioms

Say I am a die-hard communist (I am NOT!) and I want to grudgingly admit that there's this one thing capitalists are right about. I believe I could say something like "now that's one for Adam Smith" or "...one to Adam Smith," but for the life of me I can't remember which one.

Or perhaps I'm wrong and none of those is the correct usage, in which case I'd like to know what the appropriate expression is.

Comment: Either preposition is fine. It's just an informal shortening of something like *"Score **one point** to capitalism for that"*. But note that *"That's one **for** Adam Smith"* can also be used to mean *"That's a question Adam Smith should answer"*.

Comment: Personally I think the question *as posed* is trivial, and shouldn't be here in the first place. But there's no point in me closevoting because I doubt very much four other users would agree with me (but probably more than four would post indignant comments telling me they *don't* think it should be closed! :). For what it's worth, I'd have been happy enough to see the more general *"Score one **to/for** X. Which preposition is correct?"* on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), and might even have answered it there. But not here.

Comment: Also note that you specifically say you want to ***grudgingly*** concede this one point. That's not implied by the usage you've suggested, but perhaps someone else might suggest an alternative that *does* carry this implication.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, it wasn't trivial for me! (to me? :))

Comment: Absolutely - there are no dumb questions, only dumb answers. But since a *native speaker* would hardly be likely to ask specifically *"Which is correct?"*, I think a question at this level would be much better posed on ELL. Of course, I may be mistaken - perhaps someone here will have something to say about the usage which *is* of interest to *linguists, etymologists, and (**serious**) English language enthusiasts*. But I doubt it. I think asking such basic questions here simply "dilutes" ELU and deprives ELL of traffic it needs in order to graduate from beta status.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I was mistaken to post on this website. I thought I've seen things like this asked here before, but perhaps I'm mistaken. In any case, thank you.

Comment: You will indeed see very basic *"Which is correct?"* questions asked here. Partly because until about a year ago the Learners site didn't exist. But mainly because even though it's there now, many new questioners don't know about it, and many existing ELU users have little or no interest in helping the two sites to differentiate themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two common idioms are:

> That's one for Adam Smith
>
> Score a point for Adam Smith

"To" can be used as an alternative:

> That's one to Adam Smith
>
> Give a point to Adam Smith

So, to directly answer your question, both of your examples are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

An **epitrope**:..
     [E*pit"ro*pe, n. [L., fr. Gr. ? reference, arbitration, fr. ? to turn over, to give up, yield; 'epi` upon, over + ? to turn.] (Rhet.) A figure by which permission is either seriously or ironically granted to some one, to do what he proposes to do; e. g., ``He that is unjust, let him be unjust still.'' [1913 Webster] ||](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/60049/Epitrope)

**Paromologia**: [A rhetorical figure in which something is conceded to an adversary in order to strengthen one's own position.](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/731986/paromology)

**Synchoresis**: [Syn`cho*re"sis, n. \[NL., fr. Gr. ?; sy`n with + ? a going.] (Rhet.) A concession made for the purpose of retorting with greater force. [1913 Webster]](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/173693/Synchoresis)

Comment: Btw, some stylistic feedback for you: If you make an entire paragraph a link it can be kind of hard to read.